# .NET Winforms DataGridView - Any way to nest?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, nested

I think I already know the answer to this, but I figured it would not hurt to ask.

Is there any possible way to nest Databound DataGridViews in .NET? What I would like to have happen is for each row in the DataGridView to have a button to expand, which would then give me a DataGridView underneath that. I would like this nested DataGridView to also be able to do this, so I could go n levels deep with them.

Is this possible with the .NET Winforms standard DataGridView? (Or another standard .NET control?) I have seen people reference some third party controls, however they are really expensive, and I don't really want to go that route.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am not certain if this is what you are looking for but we have a similar requirement and use **Mark Rideout**'s **TreeGridView**. It's free. But it does require that you do a certain amount of plumbing to hook it up to your datasource.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

His blog is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markrideout/archive/2006/01/18/new-link-for-treegridview.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markrideout/archive/2006/01/08/510700.aspx) but sadly it seems as though the zip file he links to is unavailable.

[This page at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/hierarchgrid.aspx) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, no, it's not possible do to this with the standard DataGridView, or any other standard winforms control, as far as I know.